# Select values with condition count() Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want select all data of values have two type 'E' in data values. In this data, we can have many `type 'S'` but it's only one value of `type 'E'`.

For example: ID: 1114 have two `'Type'`: `'E'` in values so show all values of 1114.

dataframe 1:

```
id /date /origine /destination /horaire A /horaire B/ Type /Other data

1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Marseille/10:00/14:00/A / ..
1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Marseille/10:00/14:00/E /..
1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Marseille/10:00/14:00/S /..
1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Lyon/10:00/12:00/S/..
1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Marseille/10:00/14:00/S/..
1112 2021-03-11 Paris / Marseille/10:00/14:00/C/..
1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/09:00/13:00/A/..
1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/09:00/13:00/E/..
1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:00/14:00/S/..
1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:20/14:00/E/..
1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:00/14:00/S/..
1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:00/14:00/S/..
1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:00/14:00/S/..
1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:00/14:00/C/..
```

data output:

```
id /date /origine /destination /horaire A /horaire B/ Type /Other data

1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/09:00/13:00/A/..
1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/09:00/13:00/E/..
1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:00/14:00/S/..
1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:20/14:00/E/..
1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:00/14:00/S/..
1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:00/14:00/S/..
1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:00/14:00/S/..
1114 2021-05-11 Paris / Bordeaux/10:00/14:00/C/..
```

I wrote this code:

```
mask = df.groupby(['date','Id']).apply(lambda x: x['Type'].value_counts())
data_set = df[((df['Type']=='E).isin(mask.index[mask > 1]))]
data_set
```

But my output is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For count number of `E` values create helper column `tmp` and caout values by `sum`:

```
df = (df[df.assign(tmp = df['Type']=='E')
           .groupby(['date','Id'])['tmp'].transform('sum').gt(1)])
```

Comment: Thank you, i had tried and it's ok. Thanks for your help. And i have a question, what is gt? And how do you use 'gt'?

Comment: @Cherrycherry - it is same like `>`, check [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html)